# Win32api send message and Pydirectinput and Powertoy (Keyboard Manager ) Not working when open the application

Tags: python, winapi, automation, keyboard, power-toys

Please Help,

I try to implement to send keyboard input in application base
on windows 11. In my try, I run my implement
application and PowerToy(Keyboard Manager) as Administrator.
And them work fine in Other app. Such as Notepad , This
application can receive keypress send by pydirectinput. But
when i run the target programs (that i need to send keyboard
input),

1.PowerToy(Keyboard Manager) can not working , i try
to re-run as admin same as microsoft document tell us. But it
not working. When i close the application it come back to
work find as i setting.

2.pydirectinput is stop working when i run target
program. i check GetAsyncKeyState it not change state that
key. However before run target program it work fine and after
close target program it work fine.

3.win32api send message wm_keydown, syskeydown wm_char
work fine in target program except vm_shift , lshift ,rshift
, alt l and r, ctr l and r but other key is work. But i need
to send shift key to target programe. I do not know why
target programs can protect other program to send shift ,alt
,ctrl but still can receive wm_message other key in keyboard
layout.

Please help me to send event shift key to target
program without physical keyboard press shift.

```
Sincerely yours
Thank you for your kind.
```